# Proving two images are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given this function:

$f(n) = 2n+1$ if n is even, and $n-1$ is n is odd. I am asked to prove that the image of $2\mathbb{Z}$ is equal to the inverse image of $4\mathbb{Z}$.

My approach is to prove that they are both equal to $(4\mathbb{Z} +1)$. So far I have proved that $f(2\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq (4\mathbb{Z} +1)$ and that $f^{-1}(4\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq (4\mathbb{Z} +1)$ but I couldn't prove the other two directions.

Any help please?

Comment: What has this to do with `general-topology`?

Comment: I don't know how the tag got there, I meant to click set-theory. I got this in my set thoery class.

Answer (score 2):

Proving $f(2 \mathbb{Z}) \supseteq 4 \mathbb{Z} + 1$: if I give you some integer $k$, can you find an even number $n$ such that $f(n) = 4k+1$?

Proving $f^{-1}(4 \mathbb{Z}) \supseteq 4 \mathbb{Z} + 1$: if I give you some integer $k$, can you give me an integer $m$ such that $f(4m+1) = 4k$?

Comment: for the first one, I'm thinking: let $n \in (4\mathbb{Z} + 1 ) $ so $n$ is odd and for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $n= 2k+1$. Thus $n-1=2k$ so $(n-1) $ is even and $\in 2\mathbb{Z}$ so $f(n-1)= 2(2k)+1=4k +1$ so it's in $4\mathbb{Z} +1$. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm finding it harder to approach the second one.